# How to reverse for loop in c# for string type ? i need to remove one character each iteration

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, reverse

```
static void Task()
{
    string x = "*";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        x += "*";
    }
}
```

it output

```
*
**
***
****
```

how damn reverse it only with "for" loop ?
especially with included loop...

Comment: What have you tried? Consider reversing the for loop  for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--)

Comment: it allow to use x += "*"; but not -=, i don't know what to try, i can't use libraries for working with strings e.t.c, only loop aaand.. yes, i tried console.writeline("****"); and 4 same strings without one * :D

Comment: `for(int i = 4; i > 0; i--) Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i));` will print 4 then 3 then 2 and then 1 star, if that's what you mean.

Comment: yes, i mean that, by how it works step by step ? and how to do that with included for loop in first code that prints 1 2 3 4 stars, just not understand this construction (new string('*', i));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's ok now

```
for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                    Console.Write("*");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just turn it around so it starts at 4 and goes down to one, printing that many stars:

```
for (int i = 4; i > 1; i--)
{
Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i));
}
```

or use `Substring` to remove the first char each loop.

```
string x = "****";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(x);
   x = x.Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP means they want to print 4 stars then 3 and so on down to 1.  Just reversing the `for` loop will not accomplish that.

Comment: nope, i can't do that :) that is question, do this only with for that included in code that print * ** *** ****

Comment: and it means we dont know that - (new string('*', i));

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reverse the loop. Just remove stars from the string, instead of adding some.

```
string x = "****";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    x = x.Substring(1); // Removes the first star by keeping the rest of the string
                        // starting at index 1. (Index is zero-based)
}
```

Note the last value of `x` will be an empty string `""`; however, this value will never be printed.

The reason you don't have to reverse the loop is that you are never using the loop counter `i` inside the loop. Therefore it doesn't matter which value it has. It only matters that the loop body is executed 4 times.

---

if you are not allowed to use string functions, you can nest a second inner loop which prints each single star. But then it is better if you reverse the loop.

```
for (int numberOfStars = 4; numberOfStars >= 1; numberOfStars--) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
        Console.Write("*"); // Note: Write, not WriteLine!
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Or you can create a new string every time

```
for (int numberOfStars = 4; numberOfStars >= 1; numberOfStars--) {
    string x = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
        x += "*";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: too easy, yes i know this resolution, but no... teacher dont want to use substring :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do, but here's a way how to reverse a string:

```
string str = "Hello";
char[] charArray = str.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(charArray); //olleH
str = charArray.ToString();//If you want to convert charArray to (already reversed) string.
```

Then, after reverse, you can start loop as it showed in answers above.